# getting the names matching to the input given

Tags: php, codeigniter

am using code as below.according to the review name the details are getting. what i require is if i give a particular word that is for example "san" for searching the names matching to that has to be displayed.that is sangee, santhosh,..... for you to understand example is facebook in which if we go to search and add some name it will be showing the names matching to that in the similar way we require the output for our app.  the input should be dynamic. thanks

```
$this->db->select('reviewee_name');
$this->db->from('reviews');
$this->db->where('reviewee_name', $input['reviewee_name']);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: you should use the LIKE operator for this

Comment: $this->db->like('reviewee_name','$input['reviewee_name']
');
thanks for your reply. i have tried in the above but am not getting the required output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change

```
$this->db->where('reviewee_name', $input['reviewee_name']);
```

Into

```
$this->db->like('reviewee_name', $input['reviewee_name']);
```

Don't do this

```
$this->db->like('reviewee_name', '%'. $input['reviewee_name'] .'%');
```

It creates another % inside %, like this

```
WHERE reviewee_name LIKE '%%reviewee_name%%'
```

For more information visit http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: I didnt know about the % being added automatically. My answer is obsolete and wrong now :(. Enjoy your incoming rep

Comment: If you see a check image just in the left side of my answer, Click it. Thanks.

Comment: input as sange. am getting the follwing output as sangeetha: 
"review_details": [
{
"reviewer_id": "6",
"reviewee_name": "sangee",
"tournament_played_c_s": "Albany, CA"
},
{
"reviewer_id": "2",
"reviewee_name": "sangeetha",
"tournament_played_c_s": "chennai,TN"
},
{
"reviewer_id": "7",
"reviewee_name": "sange ",
"tournament_played_c_s": "karnataka,bangalore"
}
],
"message": "Review user details retrieved successfully."
}
}
 
but when am giving input as sang nothing is getting. what is the reason for this?

Comment: Can you give further information for your problem. We meet the codeigniter standards already.

Comment: if i give input as "san" it have to display names starting with san like santhosh,sangeetha,sankar.........

Answer (score 0):

You will probably get better results using something similar to

```
$this->db->select('reviewee_name');
$this->db->from('reviews');
$this->db->like('reviewee_name', $input['reviewee_name']);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Although this is untested.

You can read more about LIKE here

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: yeah they arent great, but their page on LIKE seems to be okay.